# Import dynamically generated script from html file with webpack 2

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack, webpack-2

I'm in the process of migrating to webpack using typescript and I have some script dynamically generated into my index.html like so

```
<script>(function(modules) { code inside ... })</script>
```

How would I import code (pretty straight compiled typescript to javasript code) from this script into my main.ts file (the entry point)? For example

```
import whateverFunction from 'index.html'
```

Of course that doesn't work but I would love to see the right way to implement it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to move that part in a separate JS file?

Comment: I can't be on a separated file. The script is then altered by the backend.

Comment: You should refactor that part of your code by using a Web API (Ajax call) or by adding the data as an attribute to one or more HTML-elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you defined a variable on index.html and you want to use it in typescript you need to do this:

```
declare var prod: boolean;
declare var version: string;

export class whateverName{
}
```

you should use the same name that used in index.html file.

Comment: So, if I need to use the class from here, how would I go accessing it from my typescript file?

Comment: The code i wrote is your typescript file, and the two variables prod and version are your javascript variables which wrote in your index.html file.